# How to set the width of a dynamically added ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to add ListView's in dynamically but for some reason it is not letting me set the width of the ListView. I was wondering if you guys could help me out.

I'm trying to build a column design (similar to Plume). Is this the best way to do it?

Here's what I have:

```
package com.reditr.column;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.reditr.connection.Reddit;

public class ColumnManager {

//some pointers to important vars
private ViewGroup mContainer;
private Reddit mConnection;
private HashMap<String, Column> mColumns;

public ColumnManager(ViewGroup parent, Reddit connection) {

    mContainer = parent;
    mConnection = connection;   
    mColumns = new HashMap<String, Column>();

            //creates listview here
    mColumns.put("reditr", new Column("/r/reditr", null, mConnection, mContainer, "reditr", null));
    buildColumn(mColumns.get("reditr"));

            //.getColumnView() returns the ListView Object
    mContainer.addView(mColumns.get("reditr").getColumnView()); 
    mColumns.get("reditr").run();

    mColumns.put("gaming", new Column("/r/gaming", null, mConnection, mContainer, "gaming", null));
    buildColumn(mColumns.get("gaming"));
    mContainer.addView(mColumns.get("gaming").getColumnView()); 
    mColumns.get("gaming").run();


}

private void buildColumn(Column column) {

    ListView columnView = column.getColumnView();

    columnView.setMinimumWidth(400);
    columnView.setMinimumHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

}
}
```

Comment: Where is the ListView being added to its parent? Usually you want to set width and height using LayoutParams in the add() method.

Comment: It's being added everytime this is called: `mContainer.addView(mColumns.get("reditr").getColumnView());`

Comment: Ahh, just realized what I had to do. I changed the code to this: `mContainer.addView(mColumns.get("reditr").getColumnView(), new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(400, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`

Comment: Alright, adding LayoutParams as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) to set the layout width and height of a View when adding it to its parent. Add the LayoutParams as the second parameter in `addView(View, LayoutParams)`.